# Implement set Interval in Angular HTTP service

Tags: angular

I have implemented angular setinterval method for triggering http service(getDeviceMobileNumber) for every 2seconds. But i want to trigger(maximum 3 times) HTTP service again only if the status code is 400.

But the current implementation(setinterval) is not waiting for response and calling the service for 3 times.

**Is there any solution to make the HTTP service call after receiving the response?**

```
this.counter= 0;
    public getMobileNumberCall() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          this.counter++;
          if (this.counter === 4) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
          }  else {
              this.commonServices.getDeviceMobileNumber().then((data: any) => {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
              }).catch((err: any) => {
                  //400 error 
              })
          }
        }, 2000);
      }
```

Comment: I had the exact same need and I resolved it with an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). Maybe this will help you to find a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use retryWhen in http.get pipe.

```
function http_retry(maxRetry: number = 3, delayMs: number = 2000) {
  return (src: Observable) => src.pipe(
    retryWhen(_ => {
      return interval(delayMs).pipe(
        flatMap(count => count == maxRetry ? throwError("Giving up") : of(count))
      )
    })
  )
}

this.http.get("/api")
  .pipe(http_retry())
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```